# Creating a sorted Linked List in Java

Tags: java, sorting, linked-list

So I am supposed to sort a Linked List in Java by alphabetical order (The nodes are strings).  I am not allowed to use Collections so I have to make up my own Linked List and sorting algorithm.  I have created a method that finds the largest (or furthest down the alphabet) word in the Linked List which work.  Now I am trying to sort by taking a linked List, finding the largest element and inserting it into a new linked list.  It then removes the largest and goes about doing the same until the Linked List is empty.  I am ending up with a blank list when I run it, what is wrong with my code?

Code that returns the largest element

```
public Link isLargest(){

    Link large = first;
    Link temp = null;
    Link current = first;
    Link after = current.next;

    while (after != null){

        if (large.lastName.compareTo(after.lastName) < 0){
            large = after;    
        }

        temp = current;
        current = temp.next;
        after = current.next;

    }
    return large;
}
```

To remove, I set the largest element to teh front then remove it.

```
 private static LinkedList linkSort(LinkedList unsorted){

    LinkedList sorted = new LinkedList();

    while (!(unsorted.isEmpty())){
        Link large = unsorted.isLargest();
        sorted.insert(large.name, large.lastName);
        first = large;
        unsorted.removeFront();
    }

    return sorted;
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, in Java there is a naming convention for methods such that anything called `isFoo()` returns a boolean.  If you want to actually get a value, you will want to name your method `getFoo()`, or `findFoo()` or something like that, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Regarding your problem, your `linkSort()` method looks like it should be adding things to `sorted`, so I would guess that either the unsorted list your are passing in is empty, or there is a bug in your `isEmpty()` method.  Have you tried stepping through `linkSort()` in a debugger, or at least putting some logging statements in to make sure that your while loop is being executed?

Comment: I'm a little confused... do you need to **create a sorted `List`** (as in the title of your question, in which case you'd only have to override the `add()` method of any typical `LinkedList`), or do you need to **actually sort** some `List`?

Comment: I need to sort a LinkedList alphabetically which i am doing by creating a new sorted list

Answer (score 0):

After you find the largest Link, you remove the Link at the head (removeFront) of the LinkedList. This is incorrect, because the Link at the head is not necessarily the largest Link. What you need to remove is the largest Link.

Comment: How does this explain why the returned sorted list is empty?  This should be a comment, and as such would be useful, but it does not answer the OPs main question.

Comment: It does not. It is just one of the problems that I see. We need to see how the method insert() looks like.